# Submitting Form automatically

Tags: jquery, forms, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ExternalLoginConfirmation", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <br/>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Email, new {@class = "form-control"})
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FirstName, new {@class = "form-control"})
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.LastName, new {@class = "form-control"})
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-success" value="Forsæt"/>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script>
        $(".form-horizontal").submit();
</script>
}
```

Here is my form with the script I attempted. What I want is as soon as this view is being called and the form should be submitted automatically on page load. Is there a way to make it like this? Or even not go to the page and submit the form?

Comment: Seems your example good enough for this. It not works?

Comment: No, the page loads and doesn't do anything.

Comment: I think because your script loads before page fully loads. try wrap with `$(document).ready(function() { $(".form-horizontal").submit(); })`

Comment: It worked, thank you. Should I delete the question?

Comment: No, good to keep it for other users if they will have similar problems. You can resolve next question if it was working solution.

Comment: Why in the world would you send a whole lot of html from the server to the browser and then immediately send it all back again unchanged? WHat are you really trying to do here?

Comment: And there is a problem with your layout if your claiming the answer you accepted works. In your layout the `@RenderSection("Scripts")` should be immediately before the closing `</body>` (which is where it is by default) and using `$(document).ready(function() { ` is never necessary

Comment: I am actually trying to figure out how to cut the page completely from the process

Comment: Then just do all the processing in the GET method that generated that  view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think because your script loads before page fully loads. Try to wrap your submit action with

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $(".form-horizontal").submit(); 
})
```